# Создание столбца в DataGrid wpf/c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Как создать столбец между двумя другими? Через c#[image: Вот что я хочу. Чтобы он сюда встал]

В данный момент xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="StudentsListDataGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Header="ФИО студента" 
                Width="190" 
                MinWidth="140" 
                MaxWidth="300" 
                Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="..."/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Между колонками ФИО студента и ... нужно вставить еще одну колонку.
Это будет осуществляться через кнопку.

Comment: Можете указать в вопросе, текущий код создающий нарисованную таблицу?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: вы можете вставить колонку сразу, а кнопкой управлять видимостью колонки, перебирая все колонки грида и устанавливая видимость где вам надо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если по простому, то у `DataGrid` есть коллекция `Columns` с которой легко можно манипулировать так, как вам захочется:

```
StudentsListDataGrid.Columns.Insert(StudentsListDataGrid.Columns.Count - 1, new DataGridTextColumn{Header = "Привет мир!"});
```

Результат:

[image: Result]

Если пойти по пути MVVM, то там скорей всего потребуется чуть переписать сам `DataGrid`, либо попробовать создать свое `DependencyProperty` (или что то на его основе).

Comment: Спасибо большое.)